# Que quiere decir este error de Composer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, composer, vps

Al instalar `Pterodactyl` en un ***VPS de OVH***, y mientras voy por buen camino, el `COMPOSER` me arroja el siguiente error:

> Problem 1
>       - The requested PHP extension ext-pdo_mysql * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's pdo_mysql extension.   Problem 2
>       - The requested PHP extension ext-zip * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's zip extension.   Problem 3
>       - Installation request for aws/aws-sdk-php 3.74.1 -> satisfiable by aws/aws-sdk-php[3.74.1].
>       - aws/aws-sdk-php 3.74.1 requires ext-simplexml * -> the requested PHP extension simplexml is missing from your system.   Problem 4
>       - Installation request for s1lentium/iptools v1.1.1 -> satisfiable by s1lentium/iptools[v1.1.1].
>       - s1lentium/iptools v1.1.1 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini
>   files:
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

¿Alguien me puede decir que quiere decir este error?

¿Qué pasos debo proceder a hacer para poder solventar este problema? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que necesitas varias dependencias para poder instalar el proyecto en tu equipo. Cada problema es una dependencia que necesitas y deberás ejecutar por línea de comandos la instalación en tu equipo para después